# How to force some words to start on a new line when they tend to overflow

Tags: line-breaking

I'll start with the example

[image: HTTP/1.0 is not justified with the surrounding text]

As you can see, the HTTP/1.0 is not justified. If it were a normal word, I would add it to hyphenation rules. But obviously I can't split this one. So how can I force it to be on a new line and do the thing automatically?

Comment: In this specific case, I think the situation would be worse if that word was on the next line : you're asking latex to decide between a 1mm overfull and a 1 cm underfull box, no wonder it keeps it this way. The question is still valid in general, though.

Comment: You could use `\url{HTTP/1.0}` or HTTP\slash 1.0 either of which would allow breaking after the `/` Of if you don't want it to split then `\linebreak HTTP/1.0` but that will make the line very underfull

Comment: Or try `\usepackage{microtype}`, it can do neat little tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very good package to improve line breaks is [microtype](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype) (`\usepackage{microtype}`).